# How can I use the C# TwilioRestClient and nextpageuri for paging

Tags: c#, twilio

I'm currently using the TwilioRestClient in the following manner (this is in a loop obviously):

```
var currentPage = 0;
private TwilioRestClient mTwilioClient;
var listRequest = new MessageListRequest()
                {
                    To = PhoneNumber,
                    Count = mMessagesPerPage,
                    DateSent = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(mDaysToSearch)),
                    DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
                    PageNumber = currentPage++,
                };
var result = mTwilioClient.ListMessages(listRequest);
```

This is working fine for me, but I'm reading the section from [Paging Through API Resources](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information)

"The Page parameter has been deprecated and may be removed in a future version of the API. The Page parameter is slower than the nextpageuri, and if new resources are created while paging with the Page parameter, consecutive pages may contain duplicate data."

And I'd like to start utilizing the nextpageuri in case the Page does get depreciated in the near future.

My question is how can I utilize nextpageuri via TwilioRestHelper (C#)? I've been unable to find examples of this and I don't see any appropriate method calls to do this.

Comment: I cannot see in the current source code after a quick look now, that the values for nextpageuri and so on are being used currently, or that that functionality that has been implemented. Based on that my guess would be, that for now, you cannot make use of the official library to implement that which you are after.

Comment: @DanDorey Here we are, a few years later, and I just realized that I, too, am not sure how to retrieve multiple pages of data using their C# Rest Client. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing is something like the following:

```
private TwilioRestClient mTwilioClient;
var listRequest = new MessageListRequest()
{
    To = PhoneNumber,
    Count = mMessagesPerPage,
    DateSent = DateTime.Today.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(mDaysToSearch)),
    DateSentComparison = ComparisonType.GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
};
var ret = mTwilioClient.ListMessages(options);

// ret.Messages will now have your first page of messages


// For your next page of results
if (ret.NextPageUri != null)
{
     ret.next_page_uri = ret.NextPageUri.ToString().Substring(11);
}

IRestResponse result = mTwilioClient.Execute(new RestSharp.RestRequest(ret.next_page_uri));
// The classes provided by Twilio do not line up with the fields return in Json for some reason, so we have to massage the data a bit.
result.Content = CleanupJsonContent(result.Content);

// Deserialize the Json content into a class.
var nextRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwilioResponse>(result.Content);

// Set the next_page_uri string value. We can't use the Uri class since it doesn't seem to be a valid Uri...
nextRet.next_page_uri = nextRet.NextPageUri.ToString().Substring(11);

private string CleanupJsonContent(string jsonContent)
{
    string ret = jsonContent.Replace("date_sent", "DateSent");
    ret = ret.Replace("account_sid", "AccountSid");
    ret = ret.Replace("date_created", "DateCreated");
    ret = ret.Replace("date_updated", "DateUpdated");
    ret = ret.Replace("num_segments", "NumSegments");
    ret = ret.Replace("api_version", "ApiVersion");
    ret = ret.Replace("price_unit", "PriceUnit");
    ret = ret.Replace("error_code", "ErrorCode");
    ret = ret.Replace("error_message", "ErrorMessage");
    ret = ret.Replace("first_page_uri", "FirstPageUri");
    ret = ret.Replace("previous_page_uri", "PreviousPageUri");
    ret = ret.Replace("page_size", "PageSize");
    ret = ret.Replace("next_page_uri", "NextPageUri");
    ret = ret.Replace("num_pages", "NumPages");
    ret = ret.Replace("last_page_uri", "LastPageUri");

    return ret;
}
```